# Tomcat7 - slow startup

Tags: startup, tomcat7

I have a problem with very long startup of Tomcat7.

It started suddenly and logs don't reveal anything - when I type 'sudo service tomcat7 start' it says OK and logs are silent for 10-15 minutes.

Then my app log says:

INFO [2016-01-14 17:38:36,336] (FrameworkServlet.java:initServletBean:463) - FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet': initialization completed in 28862 ms

28 seconds is obviously not true, and I have no idea where it hangs because logs don't say anything.

The problem is NOT in entropy because I don't use it for anything, and besides, I already did everything related to fixing that problem, just in case.

EDIT:
I just found that it's actually .war deployment that's taking so long. I tried with older versions of the app and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. App developer was using some old server as one of the data sources and for some reason app was waiting for 15 minutes before the timeout, without any warning in the log.

Answer (score 0):

In case your app is ok you have to edit java.security file and change

securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom with securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom

This solution is in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp#